# BASH: dealing with duplicates using md5sum

Tags: arrays, bash, duplicates, md5, md5sum

I managed to separate hash from file path while finding duplicates in my directory. My next task is to print only the duplicates (ex: 3 files, 2 duplicates).

What I did so far is placing the output in an array like this:

`arr=( $(find $1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum | sort | uniq -w32 --all-repeated=separate) )`

I need to count the number of duplicates of each file(not original), get the size of each and list their paths respectively.

I tried to do a for loop in my arr, but I can't compare hashes, it gives me the `value too great for base` error.

Any tips would be great.

**SOLVED**

```
for ((i = 0 ; i < ${#arr[@]} ; i++ ))
do 
//...compare here
done
```

Comment: What does your for loop look like?  How are you comparing hashes?

Comment: "value too great for base" sounds like you're trying to compare the hashes as integers, while what you should be doing is string compares. As @DigitalTrauma said, show your code.

Comment: My problem is actually solved I had to use the forloop instead of: for i in arr. Then I simply use ${arr[i]} to iterate and then compare!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution for looping:

```
for ((i=0 ; i<${#arr[@]} ; i++ ))
do 
//...compare here
done
```

make sure to keep the spaces when initializing 'i' and comparing it..